# Can I use AVX2 scatter instructions to speed-up some loads?

Tags: c++, avx2

I have profiled an AVX2-heavy function I have, and the bottlenecks look like the following:

```
std::uint64_t data[8];

// Some computation that fills data

std::uint64_t X[4] = { data[7], data[5], data[3], data[1] };
__m256i vec = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i*>(X));

// Compute more with vec
// Later on use data[6], data[4], data[2], and data[0] in a similar fashion
```

In reality, the arrays are also suitably aligned (so `load` instead of `loadu`). But the question is, is there a faster way of doing this with AVX(2)? Specifically, I was looking at the gather instructions. Can I use them to initialize `vec` from `data`? Or are some other instructions worth a try here?

Comment: Did you mean to say "AVX2 gather"? You're attempting a gather operation and AVX2 doesn't have scatter.

Comment: In this specific case, you can do it with two loads and two permutes. that'll be faster than a gather.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. You will need 2 permutes and two unpacks. I forgot that AVX/AVX2 has no instruction to shuffle both within and across 128-bit lanes at the same time. So you'll need to do it two steps. Two calls `_mm256_permute2x128_si256` and a call to `_mm256_unpacklo_epi64` + ``_mm256_unpackhi_epi64`` should do it. I don't have an AVX2 machine atm to work out the constants that are needed.

Comment: gcc suggests that vpunpckhqdq+vpermq 39 does the trick after the 2 loads.

Comment: Or 2 vmovq, 2 vpinsrq and 1 vinserti128 if you want to stick to AVX. It would be interesting to know what your compiler currently generates for your code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to comment without knowing what code your compiler generates, but here are some things my compiler (gcc) has to say.

```
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
typedef uint64_t vec2 __attribute__((vector_size(8*sizeof(uint64_t))));
typedef uint64_t vec __attribute__((vector_size(4*sizeof(uint64_t))));
vec f(vec a,vec b){
  vec i={7,5,3,1};
  return __builtin_shuffle(a,b,i);
}
vec g(vec2 x){
  vec r={x[7],x[5],x[3],x[1]};
  return r;
}
```

I get for f:

```
vpunpckhqdq %ymm1, %ymm0, %ymm1
vpermq  $39, %ymm1, %ymm0
```

I am passing the vectors by value, passing them via pointers would give:

```
vmovdqa (%rdi), %ymm0
vpunpckhqdq (%rsi), %ymm0, %ymm0
vpermq  $39, %ymm0, %ymm0
```

and for g:

```
vmovq   32(%rsp), %xmm2
vmovq   64(%rsp), %xmm3
vpinsrq $1, 16(%rsp), %xmm2, %xmm1
vpinsrq $1, 48(%rsp), %xmm3, %xmm0
vinserti128 $0x1, %xmm1, %ymm0, %ymm0
```